# Jenkinsfile: How to parameterise Credential Id as per branch name?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am using credentials plugin in my Jenkinsfile like below-

```
stage("stage name"){
    steps{
        withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'credId', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]){
            sh'''
                statement 1
                statement 2
             '''
        }
    }
}
```

As per new requirement, I need to different credentials id as per branch name. That means if branch name is master, I should use credentialsId:'mastercred' and for other branches, I should use credentialsId:'othercred'. The code in "withCredentials" block will be the same for, the only change will be with credentialsId.

I don't want to duplicate code. Is there any way to parameterise this credentialsId?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read the branch name variable, and set the a `credentialId` variable to use on withCredentials would the work. For example:

```
stage("stage name"){
    steps{

        if (env.BRANCH_NAME == "master"){
            credentialId = "mastercred"
        }else
            credentialId = "othercred"
        }

        withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: "${credentialId}", usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]){
            sh'''
                statement 1
                statement 2
             '''
        }
    }
}
```